# Keep the tabbar always show

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2, tabpanel

I'm a sencha touch beginner and i'm developing a web app used the sencha touch and Sencha Architect.i'm use the tab layout.I want to keep the bottom tabbar always show.
For example:
http://dev.rainbowriders.dk/podcast/public/podcast.jpg

When i tap the list item.I used the below code to move to another view.

```
        var nav = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#nav')[0];
    nav.push({
        xtype: 'episodes',
        title: 'Episodes'
    });
```

The problem is when i move to episodes view.the bottom tabbar will be hidden.Like this
http://dev.rainbowriders.dk/podcast/public/episodes.jpg

is there any kind person can tell me how to keep the tabbar always show?i don't want to add the Episodes view(second screenshot) to TabPanel.because it's should be Podcast view(first screenshot) child view.So what i want to see the result is when i move to Episodes view.the bottom tabbar still show and keep the first tab activated.

I'm sorry about my poor english.I hope I described my questions clearly.thanks.
Below are whole code:
Main view

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MainView', {
extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
alias: 'widget.mainview',

requires: [
    'MyApp.view.MyTab'
],

config: {
    itemId: 'nav',
    navigationBar: {
        baseCls: 'x-navigation',
        docked: 'top',
        itemId: 'navbar',
        minHeight: '50px',
        layout: {
            align: 'end',
            type: 'hbox'
        },
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                align: 'right',
                centered: false,
                hidden: false,
                itemId: 'editPodcast',
                ui: 'plain',
                iconCls: 'pencil'
            }
        ]
    },
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'mytab',
            title: 'My Podcast'
        }
    ]
}
```

});

TabPanel:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyTab', {
extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
alias: 'widget.mytab',

requires: [
    'MyApp.view.Podcast',
    'MyApp.view.Category',
    'MyApp.view.Setting'
],

config: {
    tabBar: {
        docked: 'bottom',
        itemId: 'mytabbar',
        style: 'background: #fff;border:none;',
        layout: {
            align: 'center',
            type: 'hbox'
        }
    },
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'podcast',
            itemId: 'podcast',
            iconCls: 'music1'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'category',
            itemId: 'category',
            iconCls: 'home-btn'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'setting',
            itemId: 'setting',
            title: '',
            iconCls: 'settings1'
        }
    ]
```

});

Podcast View:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Podcast', {
extend: 'Ext.Container',
alias: 'widget.podcast',

config: {
    ui: '',
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox'
    },
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            flex: 1,
            docked: 'top',
            style: 'border: none;\r\nbackground: #8fced6;',
            layout: {
                align: 'center',
                pack: 'center',
                type: 'hbox'
            },
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'searchfield',
                    itemId: 'mysearchfield',
                    width: 220,
                    label: ''
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'spacer'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'segmentedbutton',
                    disabled: false,
                    itemId: 'segmentbtn',
                    ui: 'light',
                    hideOnMaskTap: false,
                    layout: {
                        align: 'center',
                        pack: 'center',
                        type: 'hbox'
                    },
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            docked: 'left',
                            itemId: 'listbtn',
                            ui: 'plain',
                            iconCls: 'listview',
                            text: ''
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            docked: 'right',
                            itemId: 'boxbtn',
                            ui: 'plain',
                            iconCls: 'thumbview',
                            text: ''
                        }
                    ],
                    listeners: [
                        {
                            fn: function(component, eOpts) {
                                var me = this;
                                me.setPressedButtons(0);
                            },
                            event: 'initialize'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            itemId: 'unplaybar',
            style: 'border: none;\r\nbackground: #F1515F;',
            ui: '',
            layout: {
                type: 'hbox'
            },
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    flex: 1,
                    itemId: 'unplayedbtnleft',
                    style: 'color: #fff;',
                    ui: 'plain',
                    width: 214,
                    labelCls: 'x-button-label unplayedlabel',
                    text: 'Unplayed Episodes'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    itemId: 'unplayedbtnright',
                    style: 'color: #fff',
                    ui: 'plain',
                    width: 48
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            hidden: true,
            html: 'Podcasts',
            itemId: 'podcastsearchtitle',
            style: 'border: none;\r\nbackground: #f25260;\r\nheight:35px;\r\ncolor:white;\r\npadding-left:10px;',
            ui: '',
            layout: {
                type: 'hbox'
            }
        },
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            flex: 2,
            hidden: false,
            itemId: 'podcastcontent',
            ui: '',
            layout: {
                animation: 'flip',
                type: 'card'
            },
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'list',
                    hidden: true,
                    itemId: 'mylist',
                    scrollable: 'vertical',
                    itemTpl: [
                        '<img class="photo shadow" src="{podcast.thumbnail}"   onerror="this.src= basicUrl + \'/img/no_img.png\';" width="60" height="60"/>',
                        '<div class="list-info">',
                        '   <div class="podcast-name">{podcast.title}</div>',
                        '    <tpl if="podcast_type === 0">',
                        '       <div class="music-toal">{episodes.total}</div>',
                        '   <tpl else>',
                        '       <div class="video-toal">{episodes.total}</div>',
                        '   </tpl>',
                        '</div>',
                        '<div class="unplayed-label">',
                        '<span >{episodes.unwatched}</span>',
                        '</div>',
                        ''
                    ],
                    store: 'PodcastStore',
                    itemHeight: 70,
                    plugins: [
                        {
                            autoPaging: true,
                            noMoreRecordsText: ' ',
                            type: 'listpaging'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'dataview',
                    itemId: 'mydataview',
                    margin: 5,
                    ui: '',
                    scrollable: 'vertical',
                    inline: true,
                    itemTpl: [
                        '<div class="pview">',
                        '   <img class="shadow" src="{podcast.thumbnail}"   onerror="this.src= basicUrl + \'/img/no_img.png\';" width="155" height="155"/>',
                        '    <div class="unplayed-label-box">',
                        '        <span >{episodes.unwatched}</span>',
                        '    </div>',
                        '',
                        '</div>'
                    ],
                    store: 'PodcastStore'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            hidden: true,
            html: 'Episodes',
            itemId: 'epresulttitle',
            style: 'border: none;\r\nbackground: #f25260;\r\nheight:35px;\r\ncolor:white;\r\npadding-left:10px;',
            ui: '',
            layout: {
                type: 'hbox'
            }
        },
        {
            xtype: 'list',
            flex: 2,
            hidden: true,
            itemId: 'episearchlist',
            scrollable: 'vertical',
            itemTpl: [
                '<img class="photo shadow" src="<tpl if="thumbnail == \'\'">/img/no_img.png <tpl else>{thumbnail}</tpl>"   onerror="this.src= basicUrl + \'/img/no_img.png\';" width="60" height="60"/>',
                '    <div class="list-info">',
                '        <div class="podcast-name" title="{title}">{title}</div>',
                '        <tpl if="type == false">',
                '            <div class="music-box">',
                '                <span class="music-icon-unplayed"></span><span class="music-date">{datePublished:date("m.d.Y")} {duration}</span>',
                '            </div>',
                '        <tpl else>',
                '            <div class="video-box">',
                '                <span class="video-icon-grey"></span><span class="video-date">{datePublished:date("m.d.Y")} {duration}</span>',
                '            </div>',
                '        </tpl>',
                '        <div class="player"></div>',
                '    </div>'
            ],
            store: 'MyEpisodeSearchStore',
            itemHeight: 90,
            plugins: [
                {
                    autoPaging: true,
                    type: 'listpaging'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

});

Episodes view:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Episodes', {
extend: 'Ext.Container',
alias: 'widget.episodes',

config: {
    itemId: 'episodes',
    scrollable: 'vertical',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            docked: 'top',
            style: 'border: none;\r\nbackground: #8fced6;',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'label',
                    itemId: 'podcastname',
                    style: 'color: #000;\r\nfont-size: 14px;',
                    ui: ''
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'spacer'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    itemId: 'btnsubscribe',
                    style: 'background: #fff;\r\ncolor: #2d5f73;\r\nborder: none;',
                    text: 'Subscribe'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    itemId: 'btnunsubscribe',
                    style: 'background: #fff;color: #2d5f73;border: none;',
                    text: 'UnSubscribe'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'list',
            docked: 'top',
            height: '100%',
            itemId: 'mylist2',
            style: 'font-size: 12px',
            scrollable: true,
            itemTpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate', 
                '    <tpl if="episode_html == true">',
                '           <div style="min-height: 125px;">',
                '            <p>',
                '              <div style="float: left; text-align:center;">',
                '                 <img width="100px" height="100px" src="{thumbnail}"  onerror="this.src= basicUrl + \'/img/no_img.png\';"  style="margin: 5px 10px 5px 5px;">',
                '                  <div>',
                '                      <span style="float: none" class="music-toal" id="music-num"></span>',
                '                      <span style="float: none" class="video-toal" id="video-num"></span>',
                '                  </div>      ',
                '               </div> ',
                '               <div class="first_des">',
                '                        {description}',
                '               </div>',
                '           </p>',
                '       </div>',
                '     <tpl else>',
                '         <img class="photo shadow" src="<tpl if="thumbnail == \'\'">/img/no_img.png <tpl else>{thumbnail}</tpl>"  onerror="this.src= basicUrl + \'/img/no_img.png\';" width="60" height="60"/>',
                '    <div class="list-info">',
                '        <div class="podcast-name" title="{title}">{title:this.subcat}</div>',
                '        <tpl if="type == false">',
                '            <div class="music-box">',
                '                <span class="music-icon-unplayed"></span><span class="music-date">{datePublished:date("m.d.Y")}  </span><span class="music-date">{duration}</span>',
                '            </div>',
                '        <tpl else>',
                '            <div class="video-box">',
                '                <span class="video-icon-grey"></span><span class="video-date">{datePublished:date("m.d.Y")}</span>',
                '            </div>',
                '        </tpl>',
                '        <div class="player"></div>',
                '    </div>',
                '    </tpl>',
                '',
                {
                    subcat: function(value) {
                        if(value.length > 40){
                            return value.slice(1,40)+"...";
                        }else{
                            return value;
                        }
                    }
                }
            ),
            store: 'EpisodesStore',
            itemHeight: 90,
            plugins: [
                {
                    autoPaging: true,
                    type: 'listpaging'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

});

Comment: put your whole code in here. this piece of code that doesn't make sense. For instance, what you used to create tab!

Comment: Thank you Oğuz for your help.i have uploaded all code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know the result.

```
config: {
tabBar: {
    docked: 'bottom',
    itemId: 'mytabbar',
    style: 'background: #fff;border:none;',
    layout: {
       pack: 'center'
    }
},
```

Try this fiddle, is it OK?

[Dock Sample](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2ei)

Comment: Gavin, try the fiddle that I posted.